# Filling Navigation property?

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to EF and in my code 1st model, this is my Locality class:

```
public class Locality : ILocality
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Display(Name = "Locality")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This is my School class which I have a navigation property Locality above and it is a 1-1 relationship:

```
public class School : ISchool
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Display(Name = "School")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Locality")]
    public int LocalityID { get; set; }

    public virtual ILocality Locality { get; set; }
}
```

Right now in my School controller my solution I have is like the below:

```
    public ActionResult SchoolList()
    {
        var allschools = schools.GetAll();
        foreach (var school in allschools)
        {
            school.Locality = localities.GetById(school.LocalityID);
        }

        return View(allschools);
    }
```

My question is that when I need to access to the navigation property Locality and I always have to fill using the code above else they will be null:

```
        foreach (var school in allschools)
        {
            school.Locality = localities.GetById(school.LocalityID);
        }
```

I read that navigation property should be filled up automatically if there is a foreign key setup? If so how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused, that `Locality` property have type `ILocality` instead of `Locality`. And EF don't consider `LocalityID` and `Locality` properties as navigation, i.e. FK, so `Locality` entity is not loaded automatically, because `ILocality` is interface, i.e. **abstraction**, that can be implemented by a lot of classes, and each class has its own properties(columns), name etc, so EF is confused and don't knows, what to do, as a result it ignores this property. To fix it, just replace type from interface to class:

```
public class School : ISchool
{
    //other stuff...

    //public virtual ILocality Locality { get; set; }
    public virtual Locality Locality { get; set; }
}
```

> P.S. If `ISchool` interface has memeber:  `ILocality Locality { get;
>   set; }` you can do this:

```
public class School : ISchool
{                
    //other stuff...
    [ForeignKey("LocalityDB")]
    public int LocalityID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ILocality Locality {
        get {
            return LocalityDB;
        }
        set {
            if (value is Locality)
                LocalityDB = (Locality)value;
        }
    }
    public virtual Locality LocalityDB { get; set; }
}
```

Also, check that *LazyLoading* is switched on.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Slava, I can see now when the table is created it automatically use LocalityID as foreign key now. However, how do I access it in the List controller now? I get error in the List View "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." when it goes to @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Locality.Description)

Comment: It happened, because you got items, then context was closed and then you attempt to get `Locality` property, but context already have been closed. To fix it you should to load `Locality` property explicitly via eager loading: `var allschools = context.schools.Include(x => x.Locality).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Slava!